# Load Model from BytesIO using Joblib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib, bytesio

I have converted a model to a BytesIO object using joblib in the following way:

```
from io import BytesIO
import joblib

bytes_container = BytesIO()
joblib.dump(model, bytes_container)
bytes_container.seek(0)  # update to enable reading

bytes_model = bytes_container.read()
```

How do I convert the bytes_model back to a model now. joblib.load asks for a filename instead of a bytestring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just do the following:

```
bytes_container = BytesIO()
joblib.dump(model, bytes_container)

bytes_container.seek(0)
model = joblib.load(bytes_container)
```